ImageVector (or painterResource) as a mask for a Composable
I found a good tutorial on how to use an image as a mask, to allow a Composable to be in the shape of an image
However, it seems to only be for ImageBitmap and I can't get it to work a ImageVector - anyone know how to go about it?

Figured it out; replace drawImage in the tutorial with:
val painter = painterResource(R...)
val size = Size(width = ..., height = ...)
with(painter) {
  drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
    val paint = Paint()
    paint.blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn
    canvas.withSaveLayer(Rect(Offset.Zero, size), paint) { draw(size) }
  }
}

